# Python Selenium: If there are multiple "div" tags, how do print a specific one WITHOUT Xpath?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to learn how to print by tag. Cannot use find element by xpath or class. If there are 4 "div" tags, how do I print the contents of a specific one?

Desired Output:

```
vjs-poster
```

Attempt 1:

```
divs = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
print(divs[0])
```

Attempt 2:

```
divs = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")
print(divs[0].get_attribute('class'))
```

HTML: (The third line says "vjs-poster" this is what I want to print.)

```
<video id="video_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" onclick="streaming();" src="/video/stream?cntId=21671&amp;quality=sd"></video>
   <div></div>
   <div class="vjs-poster" tabindex="-1" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://[REDACTED].com/images/V15064/720X480/720x480/nt/4.jpg&quot;);"></div>
   <div class="vjs-text-track-display vjs-hidden" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></div>
   <div class="vjs-loading-spinner" dir="ltr"></div>
```

[image: Screenshot of HTML]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print the value of the *class* attribute ***vjs-poster*** of the second *`<div>`* you can use:

```
print(driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "div")[1].get_attribute('class'))
```

You can also use a *css_selector* as:

```
print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "video.vjs-tech#video_html5_api +div +div").get_attribute('class'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try locating that element based on it class name and style or any one of them if the locator will still be unique.
You try this:

```py
class_val = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@style,'https://[REDACTED].com/images')").get_attribute('class')
print(class_val)
```

Comment: Fam I literally said without Xpath.

Comment: I saw that, but I don't understand why not to use XPath?

Comment: Because the goal is to learn how to use tags.

Comment: But you have to locate the element uniquely! There are a lot of `div` tags on the page!

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of a tag? If there are a ton of div tags, does that make tags useless?

Comment: In our world. you can sort people by these categories: having a car, having a helicopter, owning unicorn company etc. Selecting people by "having a car" will make some selection, but since there are a lot of people having a car such selection will not be effective...